# how to implement the autoresizing UITextView vertically?

Tags: ios, uitextview, textfield, autoresize

First look at the screenshot:
[image]

second press the return button, the screenshot for your reference:
[image]

[image]

after four times click

return

button, the height of text field will not be higher any more.

now here is the question: how can I implement the function of textfield? and what about the background Image behind the text Field , should auto resize too?  if there are any solution, let me know! thanks very much----

Answer (score 1):

Make it `UITextView` not a text field, track the text changes at `shouldChangeTextInRange` of the `textView` delegate.

In this method calculate the number of lines (textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight), compare it with the previous value to decide whether you need to proceed or just return. If the number of lines is changed, check whether the `textView` is already displaying the maximum number of lines (that must be 3 on the image) and based on the results you will change the `textView`, it's superview and a button frames (you can also make it animated easily) and probably scroll the text to the change region with `scrollRangeToVisible`.